# Angular Material SideNav - Rail mode hidden on mobile

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using the excellent Rail directive for Angular Material SideNav component written by Jordan Hall https://github.com/Jordan-Hall/angular-material-rail-drawer-plugin

The directive adds a new mode for the sidenav, which creates a "rail" view that mimics the sidenav in Visual Studio Code. What I am trying to do is have that rail completely hidden when the app is in low resolution mode (mobile or less than small).

I tried binding the "mode" property to a class property which swaps between "over" and "rail" based on a media query in the class:

```
<mat-sidenav #appDrawer [mode]="sideNavMode" [opened]="isOpen">

sideNavMode: string {
   if (this.media.isActive('gt-sm')) {
   return 'rail';}
   return 'over';
}
```

This works perfectly when I switch between the standard sidenav modes, "over", "side" and "push", but will not work for the mode "rail". If I bind the mode property to "rail", the rail directive extension is never used, and the sidenav behaves as the original "over". I see other people have raised exactly the same issue with the developer - but he is unable to help at the moment.

I have done some general research as to why extension directives might behave like this, but have been unable to understand the cause.

I also tried coding around the issue - having two versions of the sidenav each with its own mode, but this causes formatting issues with the margins and flexlayout.

Edit:
Original example from Author's page
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-mini-variant

Example with bound "mode" property, not working:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-mini-variant-ubxuto

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

First you need to add the following imports:

```
import { MatDrawer, MatSidenav } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
```

You then need to target the sidenav using ViewChild:

```
@ViewChild(MatSidenav) appDrawer: MatSidenav;
```

After you have that you just need to add the following to your constructor:

```
  constructor(breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {
    console.log(this.appDrawer)
    breakpointObserver.observe([
      Breakpoints.HandsetLandscape,
      Breakpoints.HandsetPortrait
    ]).subscribe(result => {
      if (result.matches) {
        this.appDrawer.close()
      } else {
        this.appDrawer.open()
      }
    });
  }
```

This is using angular materials layout CDK to handle different breakpoints, its then open and closing it depending on if it matches the breakpoints (handset landscape and portrait).

You can find a working example here:
https://angular-material-mini-variant-4csyf5.stackblitz.io

Comment: This still isn't swapping between the 3 modes in the example. It still seems to ignore the "rail" mode as per my initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use **npm**..?
if you didn't try this...

```
npm i angular-material-rail-drawer
```

As i feel I just fixed your code...

`Editor Link` : [Editor Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-mini-variant-oqdviu?)

```
I think this will make you satisfy.
Thank you.....
```

Comment: Yes, that's how I installed the package. I'll set up a stackblitz to display the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have added some examples and redefined the question to better explain the issue I am experiencing.

Comment: I just fixed my answer again according to your answer... take a look... thank you..

Comment: I think you have misunderstood me. I need the sidenav to switch between Rail, Over and hidden based on clicking each of the buttons in the example.

It works perfectly on "rail" only, but I can't bind the property to a field so the buttons change between the different modes.

Comment: @Molloch I think you need to use one variable to work with it, replace `[mode]="sidenavMode"` and in `(click)="abcd"` append this `(click)="sidenavMode='abcd'"` and it will work.

Comment: That's how it is set up in the demo. It still isn't ever showing 'Rail' mode.

Comment: @Molloch yeah on **Github** repository there are lots of issues with this.. but owner didn't give a reasonable answer yet..

**I just updated my previous answered my editor link..
refer to them and try to change **mode** **